# How is True < 2 implemented?

Tags: python, boolean, python-2.x, comparison-operators

It's not implemented directly on bool.

```
>>> True.__lt__(2)
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__lt__'
```

And it's apparently not implemented on `int` either:

```
>>> super(bool, True).__lt__(2)
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__lt__'
```

There is no reflected version of `__lt__` for `2` to control the operation, and since `int` type is not a subclass of `bool` that would never work anyway.

Python 3 behaves as expected:

```
>>> True.__lt__(2)
True
```

So, how is `True < 2` implemented in Python 2?

Comment: Via an implicit conversion to an integer maybe?

Comment: You might find this trick funny: `[exprFalse, exprTrue][condition]` is equivalent to `exprTrue if condition else exprFalse`

Comment: @BlackBear except that it evaluates both. `print("True") if condition else print("False")` vs `[print("False"), print("True")][condition]`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You didn't find `super(bool, True).__lt__` because `int` uses the legacy `__cmp__` method instead of rich comparisons on Python 2. It's `int.__cmp__`.

Answer (score 50):

`True` is equal to 1 in Python (which is why it's less than 2) and `bool` is a subclass of `int`: basically, `False` and `True` are 0 and 1 with funky `repr()`s.

As to how comparison is implemented on integers, Python uses `__cmp__()`, which is the old-school way of writing comparisons in Python. (Python 3 doesn't support `__cmp__()`, which is why it's implemented as `__lt__()` there.) See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__

Comment: Ah, yes that's it.  I'd forgotten about ol' `__cmp__`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`True` is a just name that refers to an object of type `int`, specifically value 1. Expression `True < 2` is equal to `1 < 2`. Same, `False` is equal to 0. In Python 2 you have a method `__cmp__`, that returns 0 if values are equals, -1 if is one value too greater than other value and 1 if is one value too less than other value. Example:

```
>>> True.__cmp__(1)
0
>>> True.__cmp__(0)
1
>>> True.__cmp__(-1)
1
>>> True.__cmp__(0)
1
>>> True.__cmp__(1)
0
>>> True.__cmp__(2)
-1
```

In Python 3 you have a `__lt__` and `__gt__` methods that are equivalents of `<` and `>`.

Comment: *`True` is a just name that refers to an object of type `int`* <-- I don't think that's right, the type of `True` is bool.  A subclass of int.  The subclass could, in principle, override the operation `True < 2` to behave differently than `1 < 2`.